# Passing variables between functions on the same screen

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Here you can see the variable called ChatID.

```
getChatId() {
const IDloc = firebase.database().ref('/rooms');
const newChat = IDloc.push({
  title: 'New chat over again'
});
const ChatID = newChat.key;
try {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('email').then((email) => {
    const membersList = firebase.database().ref('/members').child(ChatID);
    const user1 = email
    console.log('user1: ', user1);
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    membersList.set({
      user1: user1,
      user2: user.email
    });
  }).done();
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error has accurated');
}
}

get ref() {
return firebase.database().ref('/messages').child(this.getChatId.ChatID);
}
```

What I need to do is to pass this variable from getChatId() to ref() and insert this ChatID inside of child.

When I do this the way I did in my code I get undefined instead of ChatID. When I try to do this with state={}, then I just get null.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please dont share code in image form

Comment: Just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a class you can do the following

```
ChatID = '' //declare the variable outside

getChatId() {
const IDloc = firebase.database().ref('/rooms');
const newChat = IDloc.push({
  title: 'New chat over again'
});
this.ChatID = newChat.key; //set the variable
try {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('email').then((email) => {
    const membersList = firebase.database().ref('/members').child(ChatID);
    const user1 = email
    console.log('user1: ', user1);
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    membersList.set({
      user1: user1,
      user2: user.email
    });
  }).done();
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error has accurated');
}
}

get ref() {
return firebase.database().ref('/messages').child(this.ChatID);
}
```